# JDBC - Query Execution

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Can someone help me executing the following SQL in java using JDBC?

```
 MERGE INTO ent_emp_policy e 
 USING(select e.ENTEMPPOL_ID,e.emp_id,e.entemppol_start_date,e.ENTEMPPOL_END_DATE, nvl(lead(e.entemppol_start_date,1) over (partition by e.emp_id order by e.emp_id,e.entemppol_start_date)-1,e.ENTEMPPOL_END_DATE) as correct_end_dt from ent_emp_policy e ,(select e1.emp_id from ent_emp_policy e1 where e1.ENTEMPPOL_END_DATE='01-jan-3000' group by e1.emp_id having count(*)>1) P where e.ENTEMPPOL_END_DATE='01-jan-3000'and e.emp_id=p.emp_id )ef ON(e.ENTEMPPOL_ID=ef.ENTEMPPOL_ID)WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET e.ENTEMPPOL_END_DATE = ef.correct_end_dt;
```

The SQL is doing the following steps:

1. Retrieves all emp_ids having more than 1 '01-Jan-3000' end dates;
2. Uses oracle window function to retrieve start date for next row in partition for particular emp id subtracts 1 day from next start date to correct end date.
3. Updates ent_emp_policy using Merge to correct ENT EMPPOL_END_DATE for that particular ENTEMPPOL_ID.

   ```
   private void processDupEndDate(long empID, java.util.Date start, DBConnection conn) throws SQLException{        
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   int result = 0;

   try
   {
       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
       sb.append("MERGE INTO ent_emp_policy e USING ")
       .append(("select e.ENTEMPPOL_ID,e.emp_id,e.entemppol_start_date,e.ENTEMPPOL_END_DATE, nvl(lead (e.entemppol_start_date,1) over (partition by e.emp_id order by e.emp_id,e.entemppol_start_date)-1,e.ENTEMPPOL_END_DATE) as correct_end_dt")
       .append(" from ent_emp_policy e , ")
       .append((" select e1.emp_id from ent_emp_policy e1 ")
       .append(" where e1.ENTEMPPOL_END_DATE='01-JAN-3000' group by e1.emp_id having count(*)>1) P ")
       .append(" where e.ENTEMPPOL_END_DATE='01-JAN-3000' ")
       .append(" and e.emp_id=p.emp_id")
       .append(" ) ef ")
       .append(" ON(e.ENTEMPPOL_ID=ef.ENTEMPPOL_ID) ")
       .append(" WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ")
       .append(" e.ENTEMPPOL_END_DATE = ef.correct_end_dt); ");

       ps = conn.prepareStatement(sb.toString());
       ps.setTimestamp(1,new java.sql.Timestamp(DateHelper.addDays(start,-1).getTime()));
       ps.setLong(2,empId);
       ps.setTimestamp(3,new java.sql.Timestamp(start.getTime()));         
       ps.setTimestamp(4,new java.sql.Timestamp(start.getTime()));
       ps.setLong(5,empId);
       ps.setTimestamp(6,new java.sql.Timestamp(DateHelper.addDays(start,-1).getTime()));          
       rs = ps.executeQuery();
       conn.commit();
   } catch (SQLException e) {
       conn.rollback();
   }
   finally {
       if (rs != null) rs.close();
       if (ps != null) ps.close();
   }

    }
   ```

Comment: define "help me".  are you looking to write a simple JDBC program that runs this?  Are you already running it and are running into Exceptions?

Comment: I tried to reformat your SQL for easier reading/understanding, but found that you have mismatched parentheses.  Fix the syntax error.  If that's the whole issue then this question should be closed as "caused by a typographical error".  This is a good example of why you should format the SQL to indicate the intended grouping of the subclauses.

Comment: Thank you, I am checking.. if I find that is the issue, I will close it. Let me test it. I checked and it's not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Basic steps are described in the [JDBC Getting started guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/getsta.htm#i1008330)

You need to:

- [Open a connection to your database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/getsta.htm#i1006650)
- [Create a statement object](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/getsta.htm#i1006663)
- [Execute the query (using `executeUpdate` method)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String))
- [Commit changes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/getsta.htm#i1019153)
- [Close the statement and the connection](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/getsta.htm#i1006638)

Sample code (copied from the documentation and slightly modified):

```
public static void main (String args []) throws SQLException
{

    String sql = "MERGE INTO ent_emp_policy e "
      + " USING(select  e.ENTEMPPOL_ID,e.emp_id,e.entemppol_start_date,e.ENTEMPPOL_END_DATE,"
      + " nvl(lead(e.entemppol_start_date,1) over (partition by e.emp_id order by e.emp_id,e.entemppol_start_date)-1,e.ENTEMPPOL_END_DATE) as "
      + " correct_end_dt from ent_emp_policy e ,(select e1.emp_id from ent_emp_policy e1 where e1.ENTEMPPOL_END_DATE='01-jan-3000' group by e1.emp_id having count(*)>1) P "
      + " where e.ENTEMPPOL_END_DATE='01-jan-3000'and e.emp_id=p.emp_id )ef ON(e.ENTEMPPOL_ID=ef.ENTEMPPOL_ID)WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET e.ENTEMPPOL_END_DATE = ef.correct_end_dt";


    OracleDataSource ods = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    // Create DataSource and connect to the local database
    ods = new OracleDataSource();
    ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myhost:1521/orcl");
    ods.setUser("scott");
    ods.setPassword("tiger");
    conn = ods.getConnection();

    try {
        // Execute the query
        stmt = conn.createStatement (); 
        stmt.executeUpdate (sql);

        // commit changes
        conn.commit();
    } finally {
      if(stmt!=null) stmt.close();
      if(conn!=null) conn.close();
    }
}
```